# OSX System Log location

Tags: xcode, localization, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to export localizations on my OSX application using Xcode 7.0.1 (7A1001) Beta. Unfortunately I'm getting a 'Localization failed to read a strings file' error. It states 'Please check the system log for more details' - any idea of where I can find (or read from) this logfile?

I am currently running OSX 10.11.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe) pointed out, it's in the console.app under the files sub-heading.

[image]